# How to make Section inside List draggable in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to make a Section inside a List draggable like this:

```swift
List {
  Section(header: Text("header") {
    Text("foo")
    Text("bar")
  }
  .draggable()
}
```

This makes list `Text` draggable, but the whole section cannot be dragged on tap on the header (Text("header")). How can I make the `Section` draggable?